# Debian Jessie: how to setup a socks5 proxy server?

Tags: debian, socks

I'm running a Debian Jessie server. I'm trying to setup a socks5 proxy server on such server:

*Firefox (local computer) <> Debian (remote server) <> The Internet*

I know how to configure proxy with Firefox, and how to configure firewall rules on the server. However my main concern is about to choose and configure a debian socks5-server related package.

- I have looked at Dante-server. However, such package doesn't exists anymore on Debian Jessie. Moreover, I don't think it's a good idea to compile such software on production server.
- I have looked at hpsockd but the configuration file seems a bit complex to fit my very simple setup. Additionally, the corresponding documentation is very difficult to find.
- I also heard that OpenSSH-Server can act as socks5 proxy server. However configuration directive like "DynamicForward 0.0.0.0:1080" doesn't seems to be available both in the documentation and in the /etc/config/sshd_config file.

So, could someone give me a way to start?

Comment: Why do you have to use SOCKS 5?

Comment: Hello, I'm just providing a VPN/Proxy service, and it would be great if I can provide SOCKS5 service too, as other providers.

Comment: No it wouldn't. SOCKS 5 is not a secure protocol for use over the Internet; it's meant for internal networks. You will be doing your customers a disservice if you offer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [hpsockd](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/hpsockd) sufficient for your needs?  Appears all the alternative SOCKS5 servers, like `dante`, survive only in unstable now, so maybe they developed bugs, exploits, etc.